# Custom And() function for Linq Expressions

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of data points in a custom class. I also have many different conditions that I need to test for in different combinations all over my application and I want to define those conditions as Expressions. Let's say my collection has Products.

Instead of writing

```
Products.Where(p => p.IsOnSale && p.Color == Color.Blue && p.Quality > 0);
```

what I'd like to be able to do, for clarity is to define the predicates in one place:

```
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> OnSale = (p) => p.IsOnSale;
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> Blue = (p) => p.Color = Color.Blue;
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> InStock = (p) => p.Quantity > 0;
....
```

and then filter my collections using these predicates:

```
Products.Where(OnSale).And(Blue).And(InStock);
```

or

```
Products.And(OnSale, Blue, InStock);
```

So I can easily see what I'm returning, I only define the conditions once, and if any of the conditions change, I can just update the predicates rather than every place I'm doing a Where().

How can I accomplish this? I looked at PredicateBuilder but Linq.Expressions is totally new to me.

Comment: So... you want your code to look like vb?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well without *any* extra work you can use:

```
Products.Where(OnSale).Where(Blue).Where(InStock);
```

... `Where` calls naturally compose as "And". Alternatively, [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) makes it pretty simple:

```
Products.Where(OnSale.And(Blue).And(InStock));
```

This just needs `PredicateBuilder` to be available with a suitable using directive to pick up its extension methods.

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I wanted to do, but couldn't figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution would be to just chain the calls to `Where()`:

```
Products.Where(OnSale).Where(Blue).Where(InStock);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yours `.And()` is exactly same as `.Where()` (at least in Linq-to-objects).

You can write:

```
Productis.Where(p=>p.IsOnSale)
            .Where(p=.p.Color = Color.Blue)
            .Where(p=>p.Quality > 0);
```